# Special character problem in ajax and javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

there is a textarea on the page. and i am sending its value via ajax.

```
var text = $("textarea#text").val();

var dataString = 'text='+ text;


        $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "do.php?act=save",
      data: dataString,
      cahce: false,
      success: function() {

                   //success


            }

     });
```

if textarea value is sth like that `black & white` , it breaks text after the `black`

if it is sth like that `black + white` it outputs like `black white`

how can i avoid this?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) the text, but I think is better to use an Object rather than a String as the `data` member, jQuery will do the job of properly encoding the POST/GET parameters:

```
var text = $("textarea#text").val();
var dataObj = {"text": text};
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "do.php?act=save",
   data: dataObj,
   cache: false,
   success: function() {
     //success
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or [JSON.stringify](http://www.json.org/js.html) which converts a JSON object to string representation.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using JSON object

eg: [{"AttributeId":"4035","Value":"Street & House"}]

or you can use URLencode before post